# Are certain types of questions ever going to run out?

Tags: discussion, questions

There are over 15 million total questions on Stack Overflow and I feel that there are many duplicates.

As time goes on and more and more questions are asked, are good questions ever going to run out?

Will the scope of Stack Overflow transform into more advanced questions?

Are newbies going to have trouble asking original questions and if so where should they go to ask without getting voted down and marked as duplicate?

I understand it is a good thing that this website now contains many answers to questions that people have, but will these questions ever run out?

Comment: Questions will never run out as new technologies are being developed all the time. Newbie questions will follow suit - alongside these new developments. Not so much for newbie questions for long-standing technologies though. If you ask a question that gets voted down *and* marked as a duplicate, chances are you never should have had to ask it in the first place. If a question is truly original, it won't be marked as a duplicate. *It's totally OK to not have to ask questions* if the questions you have in mind have already been answered somewhere.

Comment: Oh, please, I do hope so!

Comment: The pool of people who should have Googled will never run out.

Answer (score 6):

> Will the scope of StackOverflow transform into more advanced questions?

I'm optimistic this is the problem that Stack Overflow faces.

I suspect the more likely problem is fewer advanced questions and more "please fix my codes" questions.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we have 11,636,264 questions, (but that probably doesn't include deleted questions). Your number seems a little high if you are only including SO.

I think that there are some factors behind what you see in the way of questions. But it's not the *topic* that dictates this, but rather the *people*.

With how big SO is, plenty of crap is posted, and it is very hard to wade through. Unfortunately the English is usually very poor for new questions (and some of these people learned English as a first language), which hides any redeeming quality a question might contain. And some people just are clueless about the mechanics behind SO. Either way, a lot of the duplicates come from these people.

I think that SO seems to fixate on those low quality questions. There may be some bias, but new posts are more often negative than positive in terms of score.

On many sites, you get up votes because you simply followed the rules. But on SO, there are a number of hidden rules that even experienced people have trouble with appeasing.

There's really not much motivation in the short run to put effort into a question. I think that I seem to get more down votes when I have put effort into a question. The one question of mine that gained instant up votes and has an entirely positive score was a Netbeans glitch that didn't involve a program at all (and it was solved by restarting things, so I ended up answering my own question).

---

The other thing about advanced questions in particular is that they may not translate well into SO format. If the problem is too big, then the solution will be a library, or close votes for *too broad*.

There's also a lot of pressure on a single answerer to solve the entire problem. I think that we need to start considering the value that an answer **one step closer** brings. I think that SO would be a lot better if answering was less competitive and more collaborative.

Answer (score 0):

> As time goes on and more and more questions are asked, are good questions ever going to run out?

You're assuming we will code-freeze all new technology and stop creating languages.

**NOT GOING TO HAPPEN**

You're also assuming that those millions of existing questions are still relevant. Like the ones for [VB 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb5) or [iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios4). Or for [HTML 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html4).